# Firebase console shows Unknown App

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I configured firebase properly, but when I try to send test notification I see

[image]

And then notification is not delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I became normal after 2 hours :)